# Pythagoras triplets to a set limit

Tags: c

I have an exercise in which all pythagoras triplets should be printed (a,b,c) up to a maximum c value. c can be defined, and if not its set to 100.
invalid arguments by the user should be printed with an return 1;

Here my code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc>=3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Superfluous argument was given! Only zero or one are allowed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char *end;
    long ende = strtol(argv[1], &end, 10);
  if (*end != '\0'){
      fprintf(stderr, "Given argument '%s' is no valid natural number!\n",argv[1]);
      return 1;
  }
   if (argc == 1) {ende = 100;}
int a,b,c;
     for(a=1;a<=ende;a++){
        for(b=a;b<=ende;b++){
            for(c=b;c<=ende;c++){
                if((c*c==a*a+b*b)&&(c<=ende)){
                    printf("%d %d %d\n",a,b,c);
                }
            }
        }
     }
 
 
return 0;
    
}
```

I cant seem to find my error, when entering no value it doesnt print anything.

I have tried to change my loops but with no success.

Comment: You should not attempt to parse `argv[1]` if `argc < 2`. Just use the default of 100. Also, it's "Pythagorean triples".

Comment: `&& (c<=ende)` there, is kind of redundant, don't you think?

Comment: @infinitezero [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) is very commonly expressed with `a,b,c`.  Choice of variable names  that match the _contract_ (pythagoras triplets) are best.

Answer (score 1):

> I cant seem to find my error, when entering no value it doesnt print anything.

Use `strtol()` after determining `argv[1]` points to a string.  As is, when `argc == 1`, code  attempts `strtol(NULL, &end, 10);`, which is *undefined behavior* (UB).

Also, give `ende` a default value.

```
//   char *end;
//    long ende = strtol(argv[1], &end, 10);
//  if (*end != '\0'){
//      fprintf(stderr, "Given argument '%s' is no valid natural number!\n",argv[1]);
//      return 1;
//  }
//   if (argc == 1) {ende = 100;}
```

```
 long ende = 100;
 if (argc > 1) {
   char *end;
   ende = strtol(argv[1], &end, 10);
   if (*end != '\0'){
     fprintf(stderr, "Given argument '%s' is no valid natural number!\n", argv[1]);
     return 1;
   }
 }
```

---

Use an auto-formatter.

---

Loop improvements.  Use `long` (same as `ende`) and consider  overflow.

```
     for (long a = 1; a <= ende; a++) {
       long long aa = (long long)a * a;  
       for (long b = a; b <= ende; b++) {
         long long sum = aa + (long long)b * b;  
         for (long c = b; c <= ende; c++) {
           if (sum == (long long)c * c) {
             printf("%ld %ld %ld\n", a, b, c);
           }
         }
       }
     }
```

---

Other improvements possible.

Comment: `sum += (long long)b * b;` is wrong! I suggest `sum = aa + (long long)b * b;` where `aa` is calculated in the `a` loop.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yes, code corrected.  (Curious, I change as suggested before seeing the suggestion.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but just to build on **chux**'s answer, here is a version of the loops using no multiplication:

```
  long long aa = 0;
  for (long a = 1; a <= ende - 2; a++) {
    aa += a + a - 1;
    long long bb = aa;
    for (long b = a + 1; b <= ende - 1; b++) {
      bb += b + b - 1;
      long long sum = aa + bb;
      long long cc = bb;
      for (long c = b + 1; c <= ende; c++) {
        cc += c + c - 1;
        if (sum == cc) {
          printf("%ld %ld %ld\n", a, b, c);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It calculates squares by summing successive odd numbers.

Comment: Nice approach to avoid `long long` multiplication, which may be expensive.  We could use `unsinged long long` to avoid some overflow, yet this is sufficient for OP.